# Reverse USB Boot Options

Tags: boot

For work purposes, I had to change my Windows 7 boot options to boot from a USB drive. It has been a while since I've used it. How do I change it back?

Comment: If you just changed the boot priorities, it would have been set to check for a USB drive first.  If you have no USB drive plugged in, it should boot from the hard disk.  If this is not the case, please provide details about your system.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem to leave it as is, however if you want to change it, you use the BIOS settings. To access these, press the relevant F key on start up (the splash screen that pops up straight after you hit the power button). It should say at the bottom which F key you need to press.